# Only enable some checks for certain inner package

Tags: checkstyle

I have this package structure:

```
my.package
my.package.other
my.package.api
...
```

Generally, i want to use some checks, but for the `my.package.api` package, i want to use some other checks as well (checking JavaDoc). I found the suppression file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE suppressions PUBLIC "-//Puppy Crawl//DTD Suppressions 1.1//EN"
    "http://www.puppycrawl.com/dtds/suppressions_1_1.dtd">

<suppressions>
    <suppress files="my[\\/]package[\\/]api[\\/]" checks="AdditionalChecks"/>
</suppressions>
```

But this will disable the additional checks for the special package (and enable those on other packages). Is there a way to do the opposite?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, you must suppress the warnings in all packages *but* `api`. The `files` attribute of the `suppress` element takes [Java regexes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?java/util/regex/Pattern.html), so you can configure it like so ([explanation of regex](http://regex101.com/r/pL1vI1/1)):

```xml
<suppressions>
    <suppress files="my[\\/]package[\\/](?!api)[^\\/]+[\\/]"
        checks="AdditionalChecks"/>
</suppressions>
```

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately i have some classes in `my.package`, and this regex does not filter them out. How should i modify the regex? I am not familiar with this negative look-ahead.

Comment: Well that's just a matter of getting the regex right. Please create an example in regex101 and tell us which lines should match, then I may try to give you another regex.

Comment: I think it should not match to `my.package`, but your regex indeed does that. Checkstyle still wants to check the classes in that package. To demonstrate the issue, i created a [sample project](https://github.com/WonderCsabo/checkstyle-suppress-package-example). It may also help understanding what should be checked and what should be not.

Comment: The test project is too complicated. Please use regex101 like in my example above. Also, try this one: `my[\\/]package[\\/](?:[^\\/]+$|(?!api)[^\\/]+[\\/])` (this simply adds an alternative where no subpackages are present). Otherwise, please ask a new question about crafting the right regex for your case, because it is really out of scope for this question.

Comment: This new regex works, thanks a lot. Unfortunately i could not illustrate in regex101, because the first one also worked there, but not with Checkstyle filtering.